# mySQL Select if no matches in other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables: Parent and Student

The student table has parent id as a foreign key, a student can have the status either FULL or LEFT. Multiple students can belong to one parent entry.

I need to select all parent rows that have ONLY students that have the status 'LEFT' - i.e. if they have two students, one LEFT and one FULL then this parent would be ignored.

I have tried a bunch of queries etc but not sure how to tackle this. I have also thought about getting all students as a query and then somehow looping through the result and pulling out the parents that don't have any FULL students - but haven't succeeded yet.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am using PHP

Comment: Take a look at => [**Visual Representation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's a great way to show how joins work. But it doesn't really help with how select the data I want based on a column entry (unless I am overlooking something?) I can select all the students and match them up to the parents fine but am still unsure how to only return data where all of the parents students have left

Comment: You're welcome. Have a look at the answer that's been given below; it looks promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use exists and non exists to fetch only parents with left status in students table.

```
select * from parent p
where exists ( select 1 from student s
               where s.status ='LEFT'
               and s.parent_id = p.id
             )
and not exists ( select 1 from student s
               where s.status ='FULL'
               and s.parent_id = p.id
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest joining the tables on the parent id and `where`'ing the query on rows with zero full students. Something like this (untested):

```
SELECT [...] FROM parent LEFT JOIN student ON parent.id = student.pid
WHERE SUM(CASE WHEN student.status = 'full' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

One poorly drawn diagram

[image]

In a simple way: 
You can extract 'left' and 'full' separately in a subquery and do the left outer join with no 'full' entry.

```
SELECT t1.p_id
    ,t1.STATUS
FROM (
    (
        SELECT p_id
            ,STATUS
        FROM student
        WHERE STATUS = 'left'
        ) t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT p_id
            ,STATUS
        FROM student
        WHERE STATUS = 'full'
        ) t2 ON t1.p_id = t2.p_id
    )
WHERE t2.p_id IS NULL
GROUP BY t1.p_id
    ,t1.STATUS;
```

SQL Fiddle link
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4249c/6